# Is there a guaranteed happens-before relationship for argument evaluation to chained methods?

Tags: c++, trim, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

I want to trim a string in C++ with this code:

```
std::string str("  Trim test   ");
str.erase(                                 /* 1 */
          0,                               /* 2 */
          str.find_first_not_of(" ")       /* 3 */
         )                                 /* 4 */
   .erase(                                 /* 5 */
          str.find_last_not_of(" ") + 1,   /* 6 */
          std::string::npos                /* 7 */
         );                                /* 8 */
```

Does the standard allow line #6 to be calculated before line #1 is executed, so that when #5 is finally called, the argument might no longer be valid?

Comment: Goodness. Not *another* one of these function-call/sequence-point questions... here we go again!

Comment: Well, if it's so obvious, why not write an answer?

Comment: I never said it *was* obvious. Simply that it keeps coming up -- often resulting in long discussions/debates/reference citation/implementation-specific results, etc, etc. This question has the twist of being a chained method vs. a "simple" function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the standard allow line #6 to be calculated before line #1 is executed.

From [the Wikipedia page on sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point):

> [Sequence points occur] Before a function is entered in a function call. The order in which the arguments are evaluated is not specified, but this sequence point means that all of their side effects are complete before the function is entered. In the expression f(i++) + g(j++) + h(k++), f is called with a parameter of the original value of i, but i is incremented before entering the body of f. Similarly, j and k are updated before entering g and h respectively. However, it is not specified in which order f(), g(), h() are executed, nor in which order i, j, k are incremented. Variables j and k in the body of f may or may not have been already incremented. Note that a function call f(a,b,c) is not a use of the comma operator and the order of evaluation for a, b, and c is unspecified.

You should rewrite it as

```
str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of(" "));           

str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(" ") + 1, std::string::npos);
```

Comment: So from reading the quotation it seems that 'yes' is in answer to "Does the standard allow line #6 to be calculated before line #1", however it could easily be confused as an answer to "Is there a guaranteed happens-before relationship [...]." You should probably clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 6 may be called before 1.

However, the code can be rearranged to not matter:

```
std::string str("  Trim test   ");
str.erase(                                 /* 1 */
          str.find_last_not_of(" ") + 1,   /* 2 */
          std::string::npos                /* 3 */
         )                                 /* 4 */
   .erase(                                 /* 5 */
          0,                               /* 6 */
          str.find_first_not_of(" ")       /* 7 */
         );                                /* 8 */
```

There's no guarantee that 7 won't be called before 1, but *it doesn't matter* since the index is still valid.
Keep in mind, this much on one line is a bad idea, and *should* be 4 separate lines at least.